# JavaScript Parse Ignore the Type

Tags: json, parsing

I am returning a json document that has a value like this:

```
  "First Name":{"S":"Jeremy"}
```

In my code, I am using:

```
console.log(jsonData.Items[0].Longitude);
```

How can I ignore the datatype (the "S") and jsut return the actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys`:

```
var jsonData = { 
  "Items": [
    { "Longitude": {"I":"8.49"} }
  ]
}

var item = jsonData.Items[0]
console.log(item.Longitude[Object.keys(item.Longitude)[0]])
```

See it in [a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaz8j2rp/).

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  This has been a big issue working with Dynamo.